# Is this a flaw in passing arguments by reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, parameter-passing

I've always considered this a flaw in the whole concept of references:

Consider the code snippet below. I can see that when I call `mod_pointer(&myint)`, `myint` might be changed. Because I'm passing a pointer to it.

But when I call `mod_ref(myint)`, it's less clear `myint` could be modified. In fact, a C programmer would think `myint` is perfectly safe from modification because it seems to be passed by value.

You have to lookup the definition of `mod_ref`, which in a non-trivial program would be in a separate include file, and module.

In fact, I'd propose this disadvantage outweighs all the advantages (none) of passing by reference instead of by pointer.

Am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>

void mod_pointer(int *p) {
    *p = 100;
}

void mod_ref(int &p) {
    p = 1000;
}

int main() {
    int myint = 10;

    mod_pointer(&myint);
    std::cout << "hello " << myint << std::endl;

    mod_ref(myint);
    std::cout << "hello " << myint << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a style thing, man. Either way you need to look at the function declaration/documentation, since there's no guarantee the parameter you pass by address is modified - that depends on the function logic. Why are you calling a function you don't understand the interface of?

Comment: A C programmer coming to C++ with C preconception is going to have a bad time, not just because of this. You should understand the argument types of functions you call, you shouldn't just rely on the call site to figure it out. C++ function parameter types are very expressive. There should also be additionally contextual clues that the function mutates the argument, namely its name and the reason you are calling it. Presumably if you call `mod_ref` you chose to include that function call for a specific purpose related to modifying `myint`, not just to see what happens.

Comment: “References make it harder to guess what a function does with its arguments” is not a flaw with references.

Comment: And ANOTHER thing: `void do_thing(&foo);` must modify `foo`, right? Wrong, it was `void do_thing(const Foo*);` all along!

Answer (score 1):

That is true.

However using reference forces you to pass an lvalue.

You cannot for example pass

```
mod_ref( *nullptr );
```

Comment: That snippet falls to compile because `nullptr_t` has no `operator*`; it has nothing to do with lvalues. `mod_ref( *(int*)nullptr )` would compile fine.

Comment: Yes but that requires active rational decisions. I can `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&myint)`  and pass it everywhere but that's beyond ridiculous.